# Update FlatList causes flickering of the Images, howto resolve?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, flatlist

I've created tiles to show the status, the status originates from a json list and is re-added (updated) each time into the `Flatlist`. But at every update, the Image is flickering on the screen, this is not a nice user experience and I want to fix this. The text displayed below the image is not flickering, strangely enough.

I've searched and read already many items about it and each time the suggestion is the add a `KeyExtractor` prop to the `Flatlist`. This is already added but the problem is not solved.

The `FlatList` looks like:

```
return (
    <View style = {[ styles.deviceList ]} >
      <FlatList
        scrollEnabled = { true }
        data = { deviceList }
        horizontal = { false }
        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = { false }
        numColumns = { 3 }
        keyExtractor = {item => item.idx.toString() }
        renderItem = {({ item }) => (
          deviceRenderItem( { item } )
        )} />
    </View>
  )
```

And the Image is displayed in the following component:

```
const DeviceTile = ({ deviceItem }) => {
  const { deviceList}  = useContext(UserContext);
      
  const IconType = ({item}) => {
    return(
      <Image           <<== This is the flickering image. 
        style = { styles.tinyLogo }
        source = { item.Status == 'On' ? require('../../assets/icon/Light48_On.png') : require('../../assets/icon/Light48_Off.png') } 
      />
    )
  }

  return (
    <TouchableOpacity style = {styles.deviceItem} }
    key = { deviceItem.idx } 
    >
      <IconType item = { deviceItem } />
      <Text style = {[ styles.deviceTitle ]} >{ deviceItem.Name }</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};

const deviceRenderItem = ({ item }) => (
  <DeviceTile deviceItem = { item } />
);
```

Any suggestions on how to debug this, how to solve this?

Thanks for your support.

I've a video to show the image flickering but I don't know if and how I can add the video to this question.